# Merging two ordered IObservables

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, system.reactive

I've got two ordered `IObservable<double>`s and would like to merge them into one ordered `IObservable<double>`. An example is given below:

```
A    2  3  4  -  -       5  -
B    -  -  -  1  5       -  6
Out  -  -  -  1  2 3 4   5  -
```

The idea is that `Out` will only produce values when it is sure of the final order. I'm sure that this should be easy to do, but I can't come with a nice solution (in this context nice means composed of rx operators as much as is possible);

EDIT: I'd like the following program to produce the following output

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = new Subject<int>();
    var b = new Subject<int>();

    a.MergeSort(b).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

    a.OnNext(2);
    Console.WriteLine("tick");
    a.OnNext(4);
    Console.WriteLine("tick");
    a.OnNext(6);
    Console.WriteLine("tick");
    b.OnNext(0);
    Console.WriteLine("tick");
    b.OnNext(1);
    Console.WriteLine("tick");
    b.OnNext(5);
    Console.WriteLine("tick");
    b.OnNext(7);
    Console.WriteLine("tick");
}

Output:
tick
tick
tick
0
tick
1
tick
2
4
5
tick
6
tick
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does it as an RX extension operator

```
public static class MergeMixins
{
    public static IObservable<int> MergeSort(this IObservable<int> This, IObservable<int> other)
    {
        return Observable.Create<int>((observer) =>
            {
                Queue<int> BufferA = new Queue<int>();
                Queue<int> BufferB = new Queue<int>();

                Action<Queue<int>, int> update = (Queue<int> pushBuffer, int value)=>{

                    pushBuffer.Enqueue(value);


                    while (BufferA.Count() != 0 && BufferB.Count() != 0)
                    {
                        if (BufferA.Peek() < BufferB.Peek())
                            observer.OnNext(BufferA.Dequeue());
                        else
                            observer.OnNext(BufferB.Dequeue());
                    }
                };

                return new CompositeDisposable(
                    This.Subscribe(v => update(BufferA, v)),
                    other.Subscribe(v => update(BufferB, v)));

            });

    }

}
```

Ad my test output is using your test

```
Result StandardOutput:  
tick
tick
tick
0
tick
1
tick
2
4
5
tick
6
tick
```

Comment: Actually the code is not threadsafe as the in theorey we could be subscribing to A and B on different threads. The code could be improved1

Comment: If you put the OnNext in a loop it'll clear a buffer if it's built up (this only matters for hot observables)

Comment: Good point about the hot observable. Anyway the code should be generalized to handle icomparables and made thread safe too. A good example of a real life merge where this might be useful would be timestamped messages. @Matt Is the solution what you are looking for?

Comment: Actually your edit suggestion on the while l doesn't work as you think it would. You would have to make more significant changes. but you could just call replay on this to make it hot.

Comment: I've added a test case to the question (I should have had this initially).

Comment: Does my implementation not do this?

Comment: Just a note, that you don't have an OnCompleted handler, so if one completes, the other will never be able to contribute e.g. your code never pushes the last value of 7